# Android Emulator issue not able to run

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

Hi all when i run my first ever android default program in android studio i got following issue

```
C:\Users\rocky\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_S_Edited_API_22 -netspeed full -netdelay none
Failed to create Context 0x3005
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
```

can any one resolve it

Comment: you'll probably have to add some code along with a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Open **AVD manager** (Android Virtual Device Manager) and edit your **emulator** and make sure your **Emulated Performace** uses **Host GPU**. Try if it works.